# How are these methods of disabling nouveau different?

Tags: grub2, nouveau

Seems that during the past few years the grub2 file on my personal computer has accumulated multiple configurations related to nouveau. I was even surprised to see duplicate ones. Looking back, I don't even know what they mean, or what they do. What is the meaning behind these configurations? I think they all disable the nouveau driver, but why are there so many? What is each one doing differently?

- `module_blacklist=nouveau`
- `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau`
- `nouveau.modeset=0`
- `rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau`
- `nvidia-drm.modeset=1`

Answer (score 0):

`modprobe.blacklist` is a parameter for the modprobe program

- `modprobe.blacklist=m1` tells modprobe to blacklist a module

`rd.driver.blacklist` is a parameter for dracut

- `rd.driver.blacklist=m1` tells dracut to blacklist a module

`module_blacklist` is a relatively new parameter for the kernel

- `module_blacklist=m1,m2` tells the kernel to blacklist modules

Neither `nouveau.modeset=0` nor `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` are related to disabling nouveau.